# Is NET::SCP uses multiple connections to transfer multiple files?

Tags: perl

HI,
   Actually i am trying to reduce the time taken to transfer N-number of files from remote machine local machine using secure file transfer, previously i used scp system command it establishes a connection for each file transfer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Net::OpenSSH::Parallel can handle several transfers in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a bandwidth cap on each individual TCP connection, you are not going to get a significant reduction in download time by using multiple SCP connections.

You can check whether you get a speed up by putting a separate scp command for each file in a shell script and timing the script. Then rerun the shell script with & at the end of each scp line. If this speeds up the transfer and you want to really do this in Perl, look into [fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) or [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager).

Answer (score 0):

I think this would create a separate connection each time.  However, scp with the -r flag (which Net::SCP uses) recursively copies all of the files in a directory with a single connection. That might be the way to go, if you have your files in a few directories and you want to copy all of the files in those directories.

Otherwise, rsync with the --files-from option should use only one connection.  (Don't forget -z for compression, or -a).

If the only reason you're considering using perl to do this is that you want a single session, then just use the command line rsync to get this effect (with --files-from).  If you want perl power to generate the list of files-from, File::Rsync supports that.